# Perforce how to Read the branch mapping from standard input without invoking an editor

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec, perforce-integrate, perforce-branch-spec

I just would like to see a p4 branch -i example, so that it reads the branch mapping from standard input without invoking an editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
C:\Users\Bryan>type foo.br
Branch: foo
Owner: Bryan
Options: unlocked
View:
  //depot/main/... //depot/bryan/...

C:\Users\Bryan>type foo.br | p4 branch -i
Branch foo saved.
```